# How to trigger azure logic app from Google pubsub service

Tags: azure-logic-apps, google-cloud-pubsub

I need to create an Azure logic app that listen to google cloud pubsub, consume the message and do a JSON transform.
Is there a simple way to **directly** trigger **Azure Logic App** when a new message in **Google pubsub**?

Comment: Could you not think from the other direction and create a push subscription to a Logic App which is triggered using a HTTP request?  https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push  I can't see any actions that deals with PubSub in the way you need it.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is no direct or simple way to connect to Google Pubsub through Logic apps you can have a look at [Google Connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-google-data-security-privacy-policy) and [Azure Logic App connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/apis-list) for further details

Also, you can raise a feature request in [Azure Feedback Portal](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/cb47c115-7926-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c) and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/ask.html) which also be helpful for other community members who want to have a similar connection.